# Why does ruby treat variables differently inside 'def' and 'define_method'?

Tags: ruby

Ruby treats local variables differently inside `def` and inside `define_method`:

```
class MyClass
  y = 2
  def foo
    y ||= 0
    puts y
  end

  define_method :bar do
    y ||= 0
    puts y
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new
my_class.foo # => 0
my_class.bar # => 2
```

I am wondering why.

Comment: It's because `def` creates new local variable scope, while the block passed to `define_method` call is a closure.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate. Not an exact one, but I think it answers your question.